# Magento 2 How to get Controller Result in phtml file?

Tags: magento2, collection, controllers, phtml

I am submitting my form data to controller and getting filtered product collection using helper function.But Now I want that result data (from execute()) in my phtml file.Then I can display those filtered products.

> Note : No need that data directly from **controller to phtml**, We can also use block or helper but the result collection I need in phtml file.

Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create function in block example as below:

```
public function getEvents(){
        //get values of current page
        $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
        //get values of current limit
        $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 5;

        $collection = $this->_eventCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1);
        $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $collection->setCurPage($page);
        $collection->getSelect()->order('main_table.start_time asc');
        return $collection;     
    }
```

Using below code you can call this function in phtml file

```
$block->getEvents();
```

EDIT: How to get post data in block. you need to add below code in block

```
protected $request;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ....
) {
   $this->request = $request;
}
public function getPostData()
{
  // you can use below code in any function       
  $postData =  $this->getRequest()->getParams();
}
```

Comment: How can we get form data in block ? If it is controller then we can give the controller name in form action but if it is block how ? Can you tell me the process @Prashant

Comment: you need to give controller action name in form action add above updated code in block and you will get post data in block

Comment: Hi @Prashant, As you said i just put my controller path in form action.In controller execute function i did not write anything related to this.And I put your edited code in one block file and called that (block) function from my phtml file (which is having form).After that I am getting this error   [Zend\Stdlib\Parameters Object ( [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array ( ) ) ]. what is the problem and how to get post data in block.Can help me.

Comment: update code with code $this->getRequest()->getParams() please check and use it

Comment: After Update Your code i am getting this result (Array ( [id] => 21 )).I am not getting my form post data.Do I need to change anything ?

Comment: Can you please add form code and block code in question so i can check it

Comment: I am sorry Actually I tried to put my form in question itself but it is not taking tags so I am updating my form code here. [<form action="base-url/testimonials/index/view" method="post" id="filters-form">
  <input type="radio" name="level1-filters" value=" level_1_filter"/>
  <input type="radio" name="level2-filters" value="level_2_filter"/>
  <select name="level_3_filter">
   <option value="">level_3_filter-1</option>
   <option value="">level_3_filter-1</option>
   <option value="">level_3_filter-1</option>
  </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>]

Comment: This is my block code [<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class FilteredCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {   protected $request;   public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
            array $data = array()   ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }    
    public function getPostData() {
        $postData =  $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        return $postData;
    }
}]

Comment: this is (list)phtml code.(the form also on top of in this phtml only) [<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$proColl = $objectManager->get('Embitel\Testimonials\Block\FilteredCollection')->getPostData();
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_encode($proColl));die();
?>]

Comment: You have to add `$this->request->->getParams();` instead of `$this->getRequest()->getParams(); ` in block file

Comment: yes,I already tried this with "$this->request->getParams()" It is also giving the same result.

Answer (score 1):

For sending data to controller to phtml you can use **registry**

**Controller**

```
protected $_coreRegistry = null;


public function __construct(
      ....

        \Magento\Framework\Registry $_coreRegistry
    ) {
       .....
        $this->_coreRegistry = $_coreRegistry;
        ....
    }
   public function execute()
    {

        $postModel = $this->_modelPostFactory->create();

        // Load the item with ID is 1
        $item = $postModel->load(1);
      //  var_dump($item->getData());

        // Get news collection
        $postCollection = $postModel->getCollection();
        // Load all data of collection
         var_dump($postCollection->getData());
       $this->_coreRegistry->register('data_test', $postCollection);

    }
```

in your **block**

```
 protected $_coreRegistry = null;


public function __construct(
      ....

        \Magento\Framework\Registry $_coreRegistry
    ) {
       .....
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        ....
    }
   public function getTest()
    {
        $postCollection = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('data_test');
    }
```

in phtml

```
$block->getTest();
```

Comment: Hi @Fme I tried with your code but it is giving this error (Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to vendor name\module name\Controller\Index\View::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Registry, none given) I am using this (\Magento\Framework\Registry $_coreRegistry) in controller constructor.How can I resolve this.

Comment: did you remove the `var/generation` folder. and can you share your latest so i can look at that

Comment: namespace vendor\module\Controller\Index;class View extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action { protected $_coreRegistry = null; public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,  \Magento\Framework\Registry $_coreRegistry ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $_coreRegistry; parent::__construct($context); } public function execute() {
       //getting here collection
        $productCollection = $this->_objectManager->create('vendor\module\Helper\Data')->getProductCollection($data);
    $this->_coreRegistry->register('data_test', $productCollection->getData());

Comment: namespace vendor\module\Block; class FilteredCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template { protected $_coreRegistry = null; public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Registry $_coreRegistry, array $data = array() ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $_coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }    
    public function getTest()
    {
        $postCollection = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('data_test');
        return $postCollection;
    }
}

Comment: did you remove `var/generation` and `var/cache` folder?

Comment: Here (phtml) i am calling that block result: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$proColl = $objectManager->get('vendor\module\Block\FilteredCollection')->getTest();
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_encode($proColl));die(); [when submit the form it is giving that error]

Comment: yes cleared all..

Comment: @shankarboss run upgrade  `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command and check and make your you set the developer mode

Comment: @shankarboss these are default magento code to pass data from controller to block `vendor\magentoMagento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Block\Edit.php` you can see the registry code their

Comment: ok, I will check there.